# Is there a way I can display records/transactions that occurred after the last time a balance was 0

Tags: sql

I have a DB where I'm pulling user transactions. The transactions show their payments trails and I need to display transactions that happened since the last time the users balance was 0. Need psql solution for this, thanks!

What I currently have as solution:
[image]

I need a solution that will only return the last two records for instance since the transaction on 2019-10-18 was the last records to have a balance of 0

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: That small screenshot is hardly visible. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). You say that this is your current solution, but this is data not SQL. So how can this be a solution? Please show your query. Is the query supposed to get one user's transactions or mutliple users' transactions?

Comment: Hi Kevin, this site is where we help each other with problems we face. So please include You own effort in your question so it doesn't look like 'do this for me' without  the 'what i have tried' part or You will not get very useful feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT * FROM 
TABLE1 WHERE DATE>=
(
SELECT TOP 1 DATE
FROM TABLE1
WHERE OPEN_BALANCE=0 ORDER BY DATE DESC
)
```

If you have multiple users and items we need to modify the query accordingly.